# Update a row of a table in a elastic pool Db using Elastic Query

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale, azure-sql-server

I have a SQL Server in which I have created 'n' numbers of elastic pool DB with identical schema and tables. I want to update a column `Column1` in a table `table1` in a elastic pool database as `ElasticDB1` using Elastic query. Is it possible? If yes, please provide sample.

Answer (score 2):

By "update a column" - can I assume you mean rename a column from Column1 to ElasticDB1?  If so, you could use Elastic Database Jobs to execute T-SQL across a group of databases. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview. Use it for execution of ad-hoc and scheduled tasks.

As for Elastic Query functionality for this purpose - this is for read-only querying.